# Is there a way to check EXM version?

Tags: exm

I just finished an update of [EXM from 3.4 to 3.5](http://file:///C:/Users/vdeschamps/Downloads/EXM-Upgrade-Instructions-35.pdf) and despite the fact, that everything ran smoothly, how do I know that 3.5 is there?

If check the DLL is the answer, please advise which one and if is there any other way to find that out?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about: shell -> desktop -> All Applications -> System -> License Details?

Answer (score 3):

You can compare bin folders of your solution with bin folder of the EXM package.

Dlls from EXM 3.4 has version 4.0.0.5643 and EXM 3.5  has version 5.0.0.1554

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

1. Login to Sitecore `desktop`
2. Switch to `core` database
3. Find `/sitecore/system/Packages/Installation history/Email Experience Manager`
4. Check its child (children) - name of the item is date & time when the package was installed and version is stored `Package version` field

Comment: This is a good way to go, but I'd add: make sure you switch the DB to core before opening the content editor.  Then you can see /sitecore/system/Packages in the tree.

Comment: @WheretheresaWill you're absolutely right. I forgot to add it